# Cisco 3548XL VLANs, no router

Tags: vlan, cisco-ios

I am working on a project currently in our lab.  I have 1 3548XL with an uplink to our telco.
Most of my Cisco experience is on the 6500 platform so I am used to having L3 features at my disposal.  Is it possible with the 3548 to have each of my nodes in a different VLAN and still get out to the Internet via our uplink?  I cannot run dot1q for our uplink.  An engineer told me this wasn't possible without router on a stick or an L3 switch.

Any advice here is appreciated, for the sake of learning, if the answer is "no", could you explain why?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 3548XL is a L2 only switch. It does not have the capability to route. If you had to use a Cisco switch to route you could use a 3550/3560/3750.

Comment: OK, so in this situation, nothing can be done without an L3 device/appliance.  For future reference anything over 1 VLAN requires a router or an uplink in each VLAN?

Comment: If you wish to communicate between the VLANs then you will need a router to route between them. If you only wanted the devices in a VLAN to communicate with each other and nothing outside of that VLAN then a L2 switch like the 3548XL would suffice.